# Not able to set item with the key in the final object

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

The value of `videoProgress` is not returned in the final object document, i want videoProgress to be returned along with the documentList item, but i am not getting it, i have set item.videoProgress too but not getting it in response:

```
const document = await Promise.all(documentList.map(async (item) => {
  const videoCount = await studentProgressModel.find({ gradeId: item.gradeId, userId : item._id, type: 'VIDEO'}).countDocuments(); 
  const totalVideoCount = await videoModel.find({ gradeId: item.gradeId, mediumId: item.mediumId, status: 'ACTIVE' }).countDocuments();
  let videoPercentage = 0;
  if(totalVideoCount > 0) {
    videoPercentage = (100 * videoCount) / totalVideoCount;
  }
  item.videoProgress = videoPercentage;
  console.log('item', item);
  return item; 
}));
```

Comment: Can you add more detail as to what is being returned and if you are getting any errors or if the property is just not showing up?

Comment: @dylanlee082 i want videoProgress to be returned along with the documentList item, but i am not getting it, i have set item.videoProgress too but not getting it in response

Comment: But the returned items have the other properties on the items in documentList, such as gradeId, _id, and mediumId?  Are they plain javasript objects and not classes?  Can you try `return { item, videoProgress: videoPercentage };` instead?

Comment: i get the videoProgress but not in that particular object itself, getting object within object. and other properties are ObjectIds and keys

Comment: What is the value of documentList?

Comment: documentList contain ObjectIds, keys, i.e data retrieved from a particular model like name, usertype, mediumId, gradeId etc.

Comment: So it is a model instance? And how you returning the resulting `document` in a response?

Comment: directly after adding this key videoProgress

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is not what anyone in the comments above is discussing, the issue is that you are not actually returning a promise from your documentList.map, but instead are just writing an async function there. `Array.map` will **not** wait for any asynchronous behavior, so as soon as it hits an `await` it returns an empty result.

This can be fixed by instead returning promises in your map:

```js
const document = await Promise.all(documentList.map((item) => { // Removed async here, map is synchronous
  // Here we *immediately* return a promise so that map can return that to the promise.all
  return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    // Now we can do all our async stuff and promise.all will wait for it :)
    const videoCount = await studentProgressModel.find({ gradeId: item.gradeId, userId : item._id, type: 'VIDEO'}).countDocuments(); 
    const totalVideoCount = await videoModel.find({ gradeId: item.gradeId, mediumId: item.mediumId, status: 'ACTIVE' }).countDocuments();
    let videoPercentage = 0;
    if(totalVideoCount > 0) {
      videoPercentage = (100 * videoCount) / totalVideoCount;
    }
    item.videoProgress = videoPercentage;
    console.log('item', item);
    return resolve(item); // have to use resolve here with our result to resolve the promise.
  });
}));
```

There are other ways to do this that don't involve an explicit new-promise wrapper, but I figured it made the promise behavior more obvious

Edit: Here's an example which can be run directly here in your browser, I have only replaced the queries with async random number generators.

```js
function randomInteger() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
       return resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
    }, 1);
  });
}

async function main() {
  let documentList = [{}, {}, {}];
  const document = await Promise.all(documentList.map((item) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      const videoCount = await randomInteger(); 
      const totalVideoCount = await randomInteger();
      let videoPercentage = 0;
      if(totalVideoCount > 0) {
        videoPercentage = (100 * videoCount) / totalVideoCount;
      }
      item.videoProgress = videoPercentage;
      console.log('item', item);
      return resolve(item);
    });
  }));
  console.log('Document results:', document);
}

main();
```

Comment: i tried this but still not getting "videoProgress" key in the final object.

Comment: I have just added an example which can be directly run in your browser to show that it will function. Maybe you can try using that to understand what is not working in your own code?

Comment: One more potential thing I just thought of @DeepakTyagi if these are mongoose model instances, if the property 'videoProgress' is not declared on the schema then attempting to add properties to them will seem to fail as mongoose adds some complex set/get wrappers. You could instead `return { item, videoPercentage }` to be able to access both the document and its percentage.